# If statement to ignore two specified values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an automated report that runs through a list of materials and pulls out any components of a finished good that are below a certain stock threshold.

I need to pull materials from one sheet to another, but ignore fields that are null or "SCRAP".

```vb
Do While l <= alarm.Worksheets("Alarms").Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    i = 2
    j = 2
    Do While alarm.Worksheets("Alarms").Range("A" & l).Text <> alarm.Worksheets("BOMs").Range("A" & i).Text
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Do While alarm.Worksheets("Alarms").Range("A" & l).Text = alarm.Worksheets("BOMs").Range("A" & i).Text
        If alarm.Worksheets("BOMs").Range("K" & i).Value / alarm.Worksheets("BOMs").Range("G" & i).Value < 20 Then
            If alarm.Worksheets("BOMs").Range("D" & i).Text <> "SCRAP" Or alarm.Worksheets("BOMs").Range("D" & i).Text <> "" Then
                alarm.Worksheets("Alarms").Cells(l, j) = alarm.Worksheets("BOMs").Cells(i, 4)
                j = j + 1
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
    l = l + 1
Loop
```

This does not ignore the null and scrap components.

Comment: You need to join the both conditions with `And` not `Or`

Comment: @Ike Replacing the `Or` with an `And` caused the script to run infinitely and crash the workbook.

Comment: What happens if you move the `i = i+1` out of the `If SCRAP or null` ?

Comment: @AntoineL Encountering the same issue, when the increment is moved outside the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Nested If Statements in Nested Do...Loops

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim alarm As Workbook: Set alarm = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim aws As Worksheet: Set aws = alarm.Sheets("Alarms")
    Dim alRow As Long: alRow = aws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    
    Dim bws As Worksheet: Set bws = alarm.Sheets("BOMs")
    Dim blRow As Long: blRow = bws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    Dim ar As Long, ac As Long, br As Long
    Dim alString As String, blString As String, bvString As String
    
    ar = 2 ' ?
    Do While ar <= alRow
        alString = aws.Cells(ar, "A").Text
        ac = 2
        br = 2
        Do While br <= blRow
            blString = bws.Cells(br, "A").Text
            If StrComp(alString, blString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                bvString = bws.Cells(br, "D").Text
                If Len(bvString) > 0 Then
                    If StrComp(bvString, "SCRAP", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                        If bws.Cells(br, "K").Value / bws.Cells(br, "G").Value _
                                < 20 Then
                            aws.Cells(ar, ac) = bvString
                            ac = ac + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            br = br + 1
        Loop
        ar = ar + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Works a treat, appreciate it!